# How to disable clickability focus for edittext in android?

Tags: android

In my application I need to display data from database. So I have used `Edittext` for displaying data. I have kept

```
android:editable="false"
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

in the xml file and it is working fine. 
But when I click on the edittext still the focus is there. 
What should I do for that? Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

very easy..

```
 android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: I tried like that ...but I want the click action not to take place when I click on the Edittext. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi I have solved this using android:enabled="false"...now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
android:enabled="false"
```